# Dynamically Parse URL in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to do an odd and even replacement in `.htaccess` to replace `/` in a url with `= &`?

In other words I have a link like so:

`page/subscriber/action/manage/sortby/id`

and I'm wondering if there's way to simply replace the odd numbered `/` with `=` and the even `/` with `&`?

I have some urls that are very long with lots of arguments and I don't want to have to write a specific rule for each one.

I'm trying to convert over a very large PHP script to nicely formatted urls and it would take weeks to find every possible url and argument combination.

Comment: Do you maybe use Yii?

Comment: So `http://site.com/page/subscriber/action/manage/sortby/id` should become `http://site.com/page=subscriber&action=manage&sortby=id` ? Are you sure you don't want to make it a URI with valid query string: `http://site.com/?page=subscriber&action=manage&sortby=id` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you want to make it in PHP script itself? I think I saw this for the first time in Zend framework, but now using similar approach in my projects.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

index.php

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$paths = explode('/', $path);
// Add some logic for showing the page you need. Maybe remove domain before processing
```

For example you can use even arguments as array keys and add argument as value for these keys.

e.g. to print paths, use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($paths);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pure mod_rewrite using two rules. This solution repeatedly applies a rule  to the url until nothing is left to rewrite it. This solution is limited by the amount of internal rewrite loops you allow through `httpd.conf`. I believe, by default, this is 10 'recursions'. This means you can rewrite up to 10 key-value pairs before you get a *500 Internal Error*. If you need more of those, consider increasing the value of `LimitInternalRecursion` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion)) in `httpd.conf`. Remember that you need to restart the httpd-service for this change to be active.

If you supply an even amount of 'arguments' in the url (e.g. `site.uri/a/b/c/d`), it will rewrite it to `site.uri/somethingcustom.php?a=b&c=d`. If you supply an odd amount of 'arguments' in the url (e.g. `site.uri/index.php/a/b/c/d`) it will rewrite it to `site.uri/index.php?a=b&c=d`. In the case of an odd amount of arguments, you can have another rule that rewrites the remaining 'thing' (in my example `index.php`) to an actual path (e.g. `site.uri/categories/a/b` to `site.uri/path/to/categories.php?a=b` by rewriting `categories` to `path/to/categories`). Such a rule must be written after the following two rules.

The solution uses the `QSA` flag (query string append). This will append the supplied query string to the previous query string (which is very helpful in this case). See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1?$2=$3 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/somethingcustom\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /path/to/somethingcustom.php?$1=$2 [QSA]
```

See [the mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for general information about mod_rewrite.

---

Please note that this method requires Apache to go through `.htaccess` multiple times. The solution will be more efficient if the rules are put in the top of the `.htaccess` file and the `L` flag is used.